# PHP Based Advert Rotation Script (incl. click/impression monitoring etc)

Tags: php, ads

I used a script many years ago that was basically and administrative backend where we could submit advertising banners (etc) and set up parameters (show forever, until x many clicks/impressions).

I can't remember for the life of me what it was called though, and I'm needing to use it again.  I thought for a second it was phpMyAd, but google's not showing anything for that (or any of my other searches for that matter).

Any ideas?

Comment: kudos = upvote (click up arrow above the answer's score), solution = accept (click on the check mark of the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, you're looking for [OpenX](http://www.openx.org/ad-server) (previously known as OpenAds, and phpAdsNew before that).

Comment: phpAdsNew, that's what I remember.. excellent, thanks a lot.. here, have some kudos \o/

Comment: No worries. :) (BTW, on StackOverflow, you can mark an answer as "Accepted" in order to give the responder kudos. :) )

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of free hosted solutions as well. Check out Google Ad Manager.